# How to enable SSL using a connection string for Oracle database?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

We already have the SSL certificates. I need to enable the secure connection.

For example, in MySQL, you can use a connection string builder (or write a connection string by yourself) and set the "SslMode" parameter to "Required". Similarly, you can set the "SslMode" parameter to "Require" if it is PostgreSQL .

How to do this in case it is Oracle?

Comment: Are you using the Oracle Client or JDBC? Has the database been configured to support SSL encryption, or "native" Oracle encryption?

Comment: There are different configurations/parameters in play depending on whether you are using true SSL or Oracle Native encryption. SSL will require an entirely different network protocol be configured on the server listener, with a different port number, etc. There's no "required" or "not" - everything on that port _must_ be SSL. With native encryption (no certs) there are parameters to enforce whether the encryption or checksums are required, and the standard TCP port is used for both encrypted and unencrypted traffic.